Stuck during Ubuntu installation in VMware Workstation 17
acquiring and extracting image from cp:///tmp/tmp5gky5lz/mount:

I have tried 5 times installing Ubuntu to USB in VMware Workstation, but all of them failed while acquiring and extracting an image from cp:///tmp/tmp5gky5lz/mount. As you can see, it got stuck here for 1 to 2 hours and then give me an errror messagebox.
I tried redownload the iso, recreate th virtual machine and so on, but it did not work.
My running memory allocation is 4GB, the CPU has two dual cores, the USB size is 31GB, and 3D acceleration is not enabled.
